# Can we add borders in excel when exporting data from SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have written a openrowset code which gets table content and saves them in a excel sheet I want to format the data in excel sheet with borders while loading any help is highly appreciated.

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Excel 12.0;Database=M:\abc.xlsx;;HDR=YES', 
        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
select * from [abc]
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure SQL, as the borders are part of the formatting, not of the data. How are you calling this statement? Perhaps it's possible to do something in the environment from which you are calling this statement (e.g. C#, VBA, JScript)?

Comment: You need a tool to edit the excel document after you create it. For example if you  have Microsoft Excel installed you can use a VBScript or Powershell script to edit it afterwards. But you need to install Excel on your SQL Server which is usually not allowed. If you want a pretty report you might want to consider using SSRS, the free reporting solution that comes with non express editions of SQL